# Calculate slope based on axis in rows

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe:

```
  Name  Segment  Axis  1   2    3   4   5
  Amazon  1       x    0   1    2   3   4
                  y    0   0.4  0.8 1.2 1.6
  Amazon  2       x    0   2    4   6   8
                  y    0   1    2   3   4
```

Is there a creative way to add a 3rd row to each Name-Segment axis calculating the slope at each point?

Slope calculated as: change in y/change in x

Expected output:

```
     Name  Segment  Axis  1   2    3   4   5
     Amazon  1       x    0   1    2   3   4
                     y    0   0.4  0.8 1.2 1.6
                    Slope
     Amazon  2       x    0   2    4   6   8
                     y    0   1    2   3   4  
                    Slope
```

I realize this might be a tricky question, just looking for some ideas here at the very least.

Comment: Is it feasible to restructure the data into a flat format? This would be easier (more logical) to work with.

Comment: Any ideas on how to do this? Given the Name and Segment columns? @S3DEV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I’m assuming your 3 first columns are actually index, as they seem to be displayed. If not, you first need to do `df.set_index(['Name', 'Segment', 'Axis'])`)

You can easily access each coordinate with [`.xs`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html) − here we’re basically saying « access the data labeled `'x'`  in the `index` level `Axis`) »:

```
>>> df
                     1    2    3    4    5
Name   Segment Axis                       
Amazon 1       x     0  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0
               y     0  0.4  0.8  1.2  1.6
       2       x     0  2.0  4.0  6.0  8.0
               y     0  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0
>>> df.xs('x', 'index', 'Axis')
                1    2    3    4    5
Name   Segment                       
Amazon 1        0  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0
       2        0  2.0  4.0  6.0  8.0
```

Then the change in each coordinate can be computed with [.diff()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html), and we just divide to get the slopes:

```
>>> slopes = df.xs('x', 'index', 'Axis').diff(axis='columns') / df.xs('y', 'index', 'Axis').diff(axis='columns')
>>> slopes
                 1    2    3    4    5
Name   Segment                        
Amazon 1       NaN  2.5  2.5  2.5  2.5
       2       NaN  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0
```

(of course the first value is `NaN` as there are no differences with element `-1`, if however you want to compute the difference with the next element use `.diff(axis='columns', periods=-1)`)

Then, this is not really elegant, but you need to add back the 3rd level of index with [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/reference/api/pandas.concat.html), and reorder the index levels as in the original index:

```
>>> slopes = pd.concat({'slope': slopes}, names=['Axis']).reorder_levels(df.index.names)
>>> slopes
                       1    2    3    4    5
Name   Segment Axis                         
Amazon 1       slope NaN  2.5  2.5  2.5  2.5
       2       slope NaN  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0
```

Then you’re pretty much done:

```
>>> df.append(slopes).sort_index()
                        1    2    3    4    5
Name   Segment Axis                          
Amazon 1       slope  NaN  2.5  2.5  2.5  2.5
               x      0.0  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0
               y      0.0  0.4  0.8  1.2  1.6
       2       slope  NaN  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0
               x      0.0  2.0  4.0  6.0  8.0
               y      0.0  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0
```

Comment: I keep getting an error while trying to run this. Error: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'